# Koalas Dataframe read_csv reads null column as not null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, spark-koalas

I am working on loading a sample csv file using koalas. What I see is a weird behavior.

The file has a blank column `area_code` which looks like this. As you can see, it is a blank column. All the rows for this column have blank.

[image]

When I read the file as `df = ks.read_csv('zipcodes.csv')`, I get the following output, which means that the column has nulls, as expected, all good.

[image]

When I read the file as `df = ks.read_csv('zipcodes.csv', dtype = str)`, I get the following output, which means that the column doesn't have any nulls.

[image]

After a closer look, it seems that the `dtype = str` is causing this column to be loaded with a string value = `None`

[image]

Any reason why would this happen. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Bhupesh C

Comment: I am probably not understanding the question well, but when you specify the dtype when loading a csv in pandas, it casts all the data in all columns to the provided dtype. In your case it's str. and str(None) == "None" same as with booleans.

Answer (score 1):

For pandas, that issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20377) and seems to be solved.

I don't know much about koalas but you can try this :

```
import numpy as np

df = ks.read_csv('zipcodes.csv', dtype=str, keep_default_na=False).replace('', np.nan)
```